# UICollectionViewLayout issue with the cell resziing

Tags: ios, resize, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I have checked the solution all over stackoverflow and came across a couple of those to rectify the issue I am facing.
Below are the screen shots of the problem that i am facing while using collectionview in iOS7.

[image: This is how it should look]

[image: This is what is showing.]

The application is toggling between these two views on every build process. Sometimes it displays the correct implementation and sometime is displays the incorrect one.

Gone through a lot of posts where extension of the custom layout with  **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** was an option along with **shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange** and **layoutAttributesForElementsInRect**. But still the problem persists.

Does someone ran into similar kinda issue? Will be great if you guys can put some enlightment to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try using something like DCIntrospect or simple logging to see what the frames are for your collection view cells and the collection as a whole.